# Are there any higher order function to return an object from an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

### **[LIVE CODE EXAMPLE:](https://repl.it/EBT3/3)**

**Background:**

Trying to learn javascript's higher order function, some redux theory and applying it through a data transformations example and have been failing for the last few hours. :(

**Question:**

How can I iterate over the `approved1` or `approved2` and return a new object bases on **2 cases**. Furthermore, is there a way to do this with a higher order function like `Array.reduce()` or a combination baked in higher order functions? **Lastly**, if the final Object is wrapped in an array thats fine too.

I want this for a few reasons:

- immutability.
- ease of testing.
- learning purposes.

**The 2 cases:**

- If **all** `dateApproved` values are `!== null` (in this example: `approval1` array) then return a new Object *(or Array wrapped Object)* which looks like:

  `{type: 'APPROVED', approvals: [...approved1]}`
- If **any** of the `dateApproved` values are equal to `null` (in this example: `approval2` array) return a new Object  *(or Array wrapped Object)* which looks like:

  `{type: 'PENDING', approvals: [...approved2]}`

---

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// With given logic this array evaluate with a type of 'APPROVED'
var approved1 = [

    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 2,
    }
];

// With given logic this array evaluate with a type of 'PENDING'
var approved2 = [

    {
        dateApproved: null,
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 2,
    }
];

// This reducer does nothing proper right now just placeholder.
function isApproved(previousValue, currentValue, currentIdx) {
    var TYPE = ['APPROVED', 'PENDING'];
    if(previousValue.dateApproved !== null && currentValue.dateApproved !== null) {

      return currentValue
    }
}

var x = approved1.reduce(isApproved);
console.log(x); // LOG: {type: 'APPROVED' approvals: [...approved1]}

var y = approved2.reduce(isApproved);
console.log(x); // LOG: {type: 'PENDING' approvals: [...approved2]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
function wrap(approvals) {
  return {
    type: approvals.every(a => a.dateApproved != null) ? 'APPROVED' : 'PENDING',
    approvals: approvals
  };
}

wrap(approved1);
// => Object {type: "APPROVED", approvals: Array[2]}

wrap(approved2);
// => Object {type: "PENDING", approvals: Array[2]}
```