# How to rewrite an Array.every() in a custom Array.reduce() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

This question is for purely for learning purposes.  [funfunfunction](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCO1cgjhGzsSYb1rsB4bFe4Q) on youtube says that

> Any list higher order list transformation can be written in [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Audio/video Reference: https://youtu.be/Wl98eZpkp-c?t=138.

**Question:**

Purely for learning how would one rewrite [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with `Array.reduce()`

This question stems from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145757/are-there-any-higher-order-function-to-return-an-object-from-an-array-of-objects)

Javascript Example:

```
var approved1 = [

    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 2,
    }
];

var approved2 = [

    {
        dateApproved: null,
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 2,
    }
];

approved1.every(a => a.dateApproved != null) ? 'APPROVED' : 'PENDING'
// 'APPROVED'
approved2.reduce(every) ? 'APPROVED' : 'PENDING'
// 'PENDING'
```

I struggle with where I store the currently passed values. Where do I store the "passed" values like `Array.every()` does?

```
 function every(previousValue, currentValue, currentIdx, arr) {
      if(previousValue.dateApproved !== null && currentValue.dateApproved !== null) {
        return currentValue;
      }
    }
```

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll update with and ping 2 mins.

Comment: I'll be in my car on my home in 3 :p

Comment: What do you expect the outcome of *reduce* to be? The first argument passed to the callback is an accumulator that will be passed the return value of the previous call (or, if not specified, will be the first element in the array). If the reduce function doesn't return anything (i.e. doesn't have a return statement), it will be *undefined*. See [*ECMA–262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce) or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: @RobG I think the final return value will be a single true or false.  This value is determined if every test case passes.  The problem is, where does Array.every() store those intermediary passing or failing test cases.  Moreover, only return a single value at the end?

Comment: The Array [*every*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.every) and [*some*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some) methods return a single value that is either *true* or *false*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` instead of `every` and make it work, but I'd suggest you to use them in there apt places. Both have distinctive requirement.

#### array.reduce

```
array.reduce(callback(curentElement, nextElement, index, array),[initialCurrentElement])
```

Array.reduce has 4 args.

- **currentElement**: By default, this will be 1st element in array for 1st iteration and then, this variable will hold value that you return. If an initial value is passed, then it will hold that and start from there.
- **nextElement**: By default it holds second or next element. If initial value is passed, this will hold first value.
- **index**: this holds the index of current element.
- **array**: This is the parent array on which we are looping.
- **initialCurrentElement**: This is an optional argument. If this is passed, looping starts with this.

Following is a sample showing an illustration:

**Note:**

- `Array.every` will break on first `falsey` condition. Array.reduce will not.
- `Array.reduce` is meant to compare 2 values of same array where as `Array.every` is meant to compare each values to an expression. Using `.reduce` instead of `.every` is just an overkill.

```js
var approved2 = [{
  dateApproved: null,
  id: 1,
}, {
  dateApproved: new Date(),
  id: 2,
}];

var everyResult = approved2.every(x => {
  console.log(x.dateApproved)
  x.dateApproved !== null
})

console.log(everyResult)

var reduceResult = approved2.reduce((p, c) => {
  console.log(c.dateApproved)
  return !p ? p : c.dateApproved !== null
}, true)

console.log(reduceResult? 'Approved': 'Rejected')
```

Comment: Oh yeah I totally understand that it is over kill reduce, this question is just an excersize to understand reduce better

Comment: @Rajesh - OP has mentioned that he just wants this for learning :)

Comment: @nikjohn Yes. Those are caveat. I have added an answer highlighting 1 major difference. `.every` will stop at first falsey condition. reduce will not. so you have to assume `firstArg` as boolean and not consider it as object

Comment: @rajesh this distinction of the previousValue being boolean has clarify so much!  Ty ty!

Comment: @MatthewHarwood I have tried to explain `array.reduce`. Please check and if any doubts, let me know.

Comment: @rajesh that current, next, starting.  I'd what always confused me.  I wish I could award you more points.  Thanks for such thorough answer

Comment: Note that your "currentElement" is actually the accumulator and is called "previousValue" in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce). Your "nextElement" is called "currentValue". I think it's better to use the specification terms to avoid confusion. Also, "*Array.reduce is meant to compare 2 values*" is wrong, it's meant to reduce an array to a single value.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
function every(pre, curr) {
  return pre.dateApproved != null && curr.dateApproved != null
}

approved1.reduce(every) ? 'APPROVED' : 'PENDING' // APPROVED
approved2.reduce(every) ? 'APPROVED' : 'PENDING' // PENDING
```

And I'm pretty sure you can do it without `curr`, just `pre`.

Comment: Correct answer however awarded answer is more concise!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please go through comments on `nikjohn`'s answer. This is an incorrect solution

Answer (score 1):

```
 var status = approved1.reduce(  val  =>  (val.dateApproved) ? 'APPROVED': 'REJECTED')
```

```js
var approved1 = [

    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 2,
    }
];

var approved2 = [

    {
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 1,
    },
    {
        dateApproved: null,
        id: 2,
    },
{
        dateApproved: new Date(),
        id: 2,
    }
];

console.log(approved2.reduce(  (prev, curr)  =>  (prev.dateApproved && curr.dateApproved) ? true : false) ? 'APPROVED':'REJECTED')

console.log(approved1.reduce(  (prev, curr)  =>  (prev.dateApproved && curr.dateApproved) ? true : false) ? 'APPROVED':'REJECTED')
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  I 'think' I finally understand how Array.reduce()'s first param 'previousValue' works.  Thanks for that concise answer.

Comment: `.reduce` accept 2 args. `currentElement, nextElement`. Your solution will fail if I reverse the order for `approved2`

Comment: What do you mean reverse the order ?

Comment: @nikjohn Still you are returning string and then comparing `string.dateApproved` which will yield `undefined`

Comment: @MatthewHarwood He means that if the order of the objects in the array is changed i.e. if the null comes in the first element instead of the second, and so on. But the updated answer should handle all such cases

Comment: @Rajesh Could you elaborate where I'm returning a string? Also, you can run the snippet to see the result

Comment: @nikjohn my bad. Boolean and not string. check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/o74n9pjw/)

Comment: Yup, the first iteration would have `prev` as an object, and from there on it will be a boolean. `Boolean(prev.dateApproved) == false`, which will always evaluate to false, correct?

Comment: @nikjohn Nope. Its not `Boolean(prev.dateApproved)`. Its `false.dateApproved` which will be `undefined`. And `undefined != null`  is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You might roughly implement it as folows

```js
Array.prototype.every = function(cb){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i,a) => i === 1 ? cb(p,i-1,a) && cb(c,i,a)
                                          : p && cb(c,i,a));
};

var arr = [9,2,3,9,12,5],
    brr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,9];
console.log(arr.every(e => e < 10));
console.log(brr.every(e => e < 10));
```