# Sum is to be calculated for the numbers in between the array's max and min value. For eg: [1,4] should return 1+2+3+4=10

Tags: javascript, array-algorithms

It seems that the compiler is not going into the for loop.The sum of the array is to calculated.SumAll([1,4]) should return 10(1+2+3+4) as output.

```
function sumAll(arr) {
      //return Math.max.apply(Math,arr);
      //return Math.min.apply(Math,arr);

        //  return "0";
        var sum=arr.reduce(function(a,b){
          for(var i=Math.min.apply(Math,arr);i<=Math.max.apply(Math,arr);i++){
         return a+b;
        }
        },0);
      //return sum;
    }

    sumAll([1, 4]);
```

Comment: nothing is being returned.For loop is not getting executed. @Rajesh

Comment: You could also use the formula, sum of first n natural numbers = n*(n+1)/2 :P

Comment: The `for` loop is not getting executed because you are returning from it in the first iteration. @aayushi

Comment: Why do you need `reduce` here?

Comment: I was trying to do it using reduce(). Why is it not applicable here @hindmost

Comment: It may be applicable, though it looks excessive in this case. Anyway you use it in wrong way.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use it in this code @hindmost

Comment: Just **don't use** `reduce` here. You have 5 answers below how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You could use directly the values from the array, without reduce.

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
    var i, sum = 0;
    for (i = Math.min.apply(null, arr); i <= Math.max.apply(null, arr); i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
console.log(sumAll([1, 3, 9]));
```

Comment: why 'Math.min.apply(null, arr)' and Math.max.apply(null, arr) is used?

Comment: To get min and max values in array

Comment: it is to get from an array the min and max values. [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) uses as arguments an object and an array as parameter for calling.

Comment: Why is reduce() not applicable here?

Comment: because you need only two values of the array and not the others, if so.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `reduce` because you don't have an array to reduce. You can however keep the for loop and accumulate the sum by adding `i` to `sum` on each iteration. The problem was that you:

- Used and unnecessary reduce
- was `return` ing immediately out of the for loop, so no accumulation of sum was occuring.

Here's what the code should look like:

```js
function sumAll(arr) {

  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = Math.min.apply(Math, arr); i <= Math.max.apply(Math, arr); i++) {
    sum += i;
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
```

Comment: If this has to be done using reduce(),what would be the code? @Hitscotty

Comment: @aayushi: To reduce you first need to build the array of all the numbers between `min` and `max`. Then you can implement `sum [1,2,3,4,5]` as `reduce (+) 0 [1,2,3,4,5] `. But that's a bit crazy.

Comment: understood! Thanks @Thilo

Answer (score 3):

It seems no one wants to use the formula for the sum of the first N natural numbers:

```
function sumAll(arr) { 
   let start = Math.min.apply(Math, arr); 
   let end = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);  
   return (end * (end+1) - start * (start-1) ) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Note: your array has limits of range, so you should use these values for loop and use `i` to calculate sum.

**Sample**

**For loop**

```js
function getSumOfRange(arr){
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr)
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=min; i<= max; i++){
    sum+=i;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(getSumOfRange([1,4]))
```

**Formula based**

```js
function getSumOfRange(arr){
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr)
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var diff = (max-min) + 1;
  var sum = (min + max);
  var total = sum * Math.floor(diff/2)
  return diff % 2 === 0 ? total : total + (sum/2);
}

console.log(getSumOfRange([1,4]))
console.log(getSumOfRange([10,40]))
```

---

**Your Code's explanation**

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    // Loop will only run once as you are returning
    for (var i = Math.min.apply(Math, arr); i <= Math.max.apply(Math, arr); i++) {
      // 1st Time: a=0; b=1;
      // 2nd Time: a=1; b=4;
      return a + b;
    }
  }, 0);
   
  // Sum = 5 and not 10;
  
  // You have commented return hence no output is given back.
  //return sum;
}

sumAll([1, 4]);
```

Comment: how do the values of a and b change in reduce()? @rajesh

Comment: `a` will hold *initial value* for first iteration and *return value of previous iteration* for other iterations. `b` will hold element value

Comment: @aayushi You can refer following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40146799/3783478) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1. Using the mathematical formula `n1 + (n1 + 1) + ... + n2 = n2(n2 + 1) / 2 - n1(n1 - 1) / 2`. Time complexity: **O(1)**
2. Programmatically. Time complexity: **O(n)**

Obviously for numbers with large range, the first way is much faster.

```js
function sumAllMath(arr) {
  if (!(Array.isArray(arr) 
      && arr.length === 2
      && typeof arr[0] === 'number'
      && typeof arr[1] === 'number'
      && arr[0] < arr[1])) {
      return;
  }  
  
  var from = arr[0];
  var to = arr[1];
  return ((to * (to + 1)) / 2) - ((from * (from - 1)) / 2);
}

console.log(sumAllMath([1,4]))

function sumAll(arr) {
  if (!(Array.isArray(arr) 
      && arr.length === 2
      && typeof arr[0] === 'number'
      && typeof arr[1] === 'number'
      && arr[0] < arr[1])) {
      return;
  }  
  
  var sum = 0;
  var from = arr[0];
  var to = arr[1];
  while(from <= to) {
    sum += from;
    ++from;
  }
  
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumAll([1,4]))
```

Comment: Time complexity is not really `O(1)` because you still have to determine the maximum and minimum value in the array (which you somehow ignored), but formula is definitely the way to go!

Comment: There is a misunderstanding on the question. I understand that the array has always 2 numbers with the format: [minNumber, maxNumber]. So, you don't have to search the numbers in the array.

Comment: More importantly, even if we want to include having to find out the extrema of the array, that is still just `O(n)` in the length of the array, not in the size of the numbers themselves (like a loop would be). So if you give an upper bound for the array length (such as two...) it is still effectively `O(1)`.