# How to replace for loop => using method like map(), filter() or reduce()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

#### Here is my code!!!

How to replace for loop => using method like map(), filter() or reduce()

Algorithm

```js
const sumAll = (arr) => {
 let sum = 0

    if (arr[0] > arr[1]) [arr[0], arr[1]] = [arr[1], arr[0]]
  
   for( let i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1] ; i ++) sum += i
    // replace for loop
  
   return sum
}
console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
console.log(sumAll([10, 5]));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Read up on Array methods on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: First example on the page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: I tried the code with a filter but I cannot check condition for min and max of this array, I don't know how to set i must be less than arr[1](max) in that method

Comment: you can use `n*(n+1)/2` to solve this problem. do not need any `map()`, `reduce()` or `filter()`

Comment: I do not still understand your idea, Atiq.

Comment: Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42362792/3551786) without any loop.

Comment: I have a problem with code exercise. I don't want to use for and while loop, how can I fix it? I recommend using ES6

Comment: Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/Phuocding/vjtn72pe/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [Gauss sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes) for [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), where all numbers from `1` to `n` is like `n * (n + 1) / 2`. then you need to subtract all previous found sum of `1` ... `n - 1`.

> ```
>  +---- 10 ---+   +------- 45 --------+
>  |           |   |                   |
>
>  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
>
>  |               |                   
>  +------ 15 -----+
>
>  |                                   |
>  +---------------- 55 ---------------+
> ```

```js
function sumAll(array) {
    var min = Math.min(...array),
        max = Math.max(...array);

    return max * (max + 1) / 2 - (min - 1) * min / 2;
}

console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
console.log(sumAll([10, 5]));
```

With reduce by using to create a temporary array.

```js
function sumAll(array) {
    var min = Math.min(...array),
        max = Math.max(...array),
        array = Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (_, i) => min + i);

    return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}

console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
console.log(sumAll([10, 5]));
```

Comment: I do not recommend using min-max :((

Comment: why? you could replace it by using your approach of swapping.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I am trying to find something new more. :). These ways are so popular.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.apply()` and `map()` then `reduce()` if you really want to.

```js
const sumAll = (arr) => {
    if (arr[0] > arr[1]) [arr[0], arr[1]] = [arr[1], arr[0]]
    /*No idea why I am doing it :(*/
   return Array.apply(null, Array(arr[1] - arr[0] + 1)).map((_, i) => arr[0] + i).reduce((e,s) => e+s,0);
}

console.log(sumAll([1, 4]));
console.log(sumAll([10, 5]));
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to understand. That's cool.